# Google Wallet Multiple Buttons on 1 Page - JWT & Callback

Tags: php, callback, android-pay, jwt

I am adding Google Wallet for Digital Goods to my simple Wordpress website. I have 5 products and do not mind if they need to be purchased one at a time (like Google Checkout). However, I am stumped with JWT.

I have downloaded the Sample App for PHP at https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-php and have identified the basics of changing my seller information as well as changing my first product (instead of the cake demo).

I still haven't figured out how to add more than one Buy Now button on a page. I assume that I need to add another payload in generate-token.php but cannot find any documentation on that. I sure hope someone with JSON/JWT could help me over this hump.

Another issue is creating a callback for each that allows me to redirect the buyer back to my website with the link and password to the download page. At this point, I'd appreciate answers to one of these 2 issues or both. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For each button on your web page you will generate a different JWT as the "name", "description", "price" and "sellerData" is different for each item:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#1

You can set only one postback URL. The postback data will contain the JWT for the item purchased which allows you to determine what was sold. You can also place additional item information in the "sellerData" field:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#5